# Knoppix only shows 2 out of 7 hdds

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, knoppix

I'm trying to recover some data from a computer. The computer has 7 disks. When booting from the latest knoppix live cd I only see 2 hard drives. Why are the other ones not showing up?

Anyone an idea? Is it because they are in raid (I thought even then knoppix shows the HDDs? )

Comment: How are they in RAID? HW RAID on a RAID card, fake RAID, software RAID (if so, which Sw RAID). Are the five missing drives on a different controller from the other two? Does Knoppix recognise the controller they are on? Is there any disk encryption used? ...

Comment: I think they are on a raid via the motherboard. I tried to decouple every drive and couple one by one. Only 2 drivers are working. The other ones don't even make some sound or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the drives on my computer too and there the also didn't show up or didn't make any sound. Only the SSDs makes a weird sound. They are all broken.